# Error in web.xml in tomcat v.7.0.61

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I get the below error in web.xml near the server-url tag. Below is the web.xml

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'servlet-url'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":url-pattern}' is 
 expected.
```

Following is the servlet-mapping tag in which the error occurs

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appcontroller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-url>/appcontroller</servlet-url>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Is tomcat giving you this error? Or some other validator?

Comment: @BrettWalker A validator in eclipse i guess!

Comment: There was never any 7.0.1 release of Tomcat. There was a 7.0.0-beta and a 7.0.2-beta released. Is this the correct version?

Comment: @BrettWalker Sorry the version is 7.0.61

Comment: replace `<servlet-url></servlet-url>` with `<url-pattern></url-pattern>` and it'll work.

Comment: Your answer is right there in your own question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code to:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appcontroller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you please add more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone In web.xml, <servlet-mapping> tag, we need to provide <servlet-name> and <url-pattern> and not <servlet-url> which Aarish has added

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appcontroller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

`cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'servlet-url'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":url-pattern}' is expected.`

Your web.xml is malformed.
You have to change the tag `<servlet-url>` to `<url-pattern>`

For an example including documentation check this out:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html

This is the web.xml for the DefaultServlet which can be used to serve static content like html, js, images and stuff like that.